# Work around to access variable and functions within jQuery .ready() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

Hi guys I need to test if a jquery script like the below one contains a given function (for example foo):

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
  let n = 5;
  function foo() {
    console.log(n * 2)
  }

  foo();
})
```

I tried this function to test whether is function or not:

```js
function isFunction(x) {return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === '[object Function]'}
```

but it didn't because of the closure and eventually, I end up with a function not defined error.

Comment: Put the functions outside document.ready. Only code which relies on the DOM being in a ready state needs to go in document.ready.

Comment: Your should only start executing code in 1document.ready1, not necessarily define the functions there. Also, your `isFunction` is a bad example, since `Function` is _always_ defined. You wouldn't be able to define a function to call in `document.ready` otherwise.

Comment: If you're writing tests, then you should be testing functionality not implementation.

Comment: Ok, but for the purpose of the test I have to deal with jquery code that is wrapped around the jquery .ready()

Comment: If a function is in a scope that you can not read, there is not much that you can do to access it. Sounds like you need to rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: @epascarello, I just trying to write some tests for jquery code that had to be implemented inside a HTML file and must be wrapped by document.ready(), and some of tests is to check if there is a function named foo for example

Comment: @MoezBenRebah That is not going to work. You are going to have to write the code in a way you can access it.

Comment: @epascarello, do you think implementing the jquery code in an external file and using **jest** 'for example' for testing would be better?

Comment: You still need to work around scope and document.ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this. Granted this is pretty outside-the-box thinking and will become broken if you change the name of the foo() function ever.

```js
function readyCallback(){
  let n = 5;
  function foo() {
    console.log(n * 2)
  }

  foo();
}
$( document ).ready(readyCallback);

const testBoolean = readyCallback.toString().includes('function foo()');

console.log(testBoolean ? "The Test Has Passed" : 'The Test Has Failed')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's a great workaround thank you!